# How to embed a static HTML page in Angular

Tags: angular

How can I embed content from static HTML page in a section of Angular page?
It is possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading in the file with fetch and then appending it to the document

it will look something like

```
fetch(myfile.html)
.then(myhtml => document.insertAdjacentHTML(myhtml))
```

try asking again, more specifically, for a more specific answer

Comment: Thanks - `insertAdjacentHTML` this is the answer to my question `https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/insertadjacenthtml-enables-faster-html-snippet-injection/`